what is the total degree of a graph or should I call it the degree of a graph?
I have been studying the topic of graph theory for several years, and I have a question about the degree of a graph. From what I understand, a vertex in an undirected or directed graph can have a degree. In the case of an undirected graph, the degree is the number of adjacent vertices. For a directed graph, the degree is the sum of the in-degree and out-degree of the analyzed vertex.
However, I am curious if there is a concept referred to as the 'degree of a graph.' I have not encountered a formal definition of this in the books I have reviewed, except for a brief mention in Epp's Discrete Mathematics with Applications. Additionally, is there any practical utility in knowing the 'degree' of an entire graph? It would be great if you could provide me with some references from books or articles that mention this concept.
Thanks.

I believe that for the whole graph, the maximum degree, minimum degree, and average degree are matters worth paying attention to.

Defining the "total degree" of a graph to be the sum of degrees in the graph is, as far as I know, just a quirk of Epp's Discrete Mathematics with Applications. It's not used in textbooks on graph theory, and it is not used by graph theorists.
It's not that this is a useless concept. Far from it; the handshake lemma (more formally, the degree sum formula), which says that the sum of degrees in a graph is equal to twice the number of edges, is one of the most useful results in basic graph theory. I'd say it's one of a few that every mathematician should know, whether or not they're a graph theorist.
However, precisely because of the handshake lemma, it's not useful to give a name to the sum of degrees. The information conveyed by that quantity is more usefully conveyed by saying how many edges the graph has!
The "degree of a graph" might also be informally used in the context of regular graphs. If every vertex of a graph has degree $d$, we say that the graph is "regular of degree $d$" or "$d$-regular", and so it's not too much of a stretch that someone might say that $d$ is the degree of that regular graph. However, due to the ambiguity, it's also best avoided.
